# ArrayList empty in a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I'm trying to do a server for my game, responsible for the authentication and the matchmaking.

I have an ArrayList of Rooms (the rooms just keep track of the list of players in a game), which I use for matchmaking.

I have two singletons, PoulpiciousServer.java which is the main class, that runs everything, and MatchmakingEngine, which is run on another thread, and handles the players asking for a room to play.

Here are the classes (I use KryoNet) :

```
package com.poulpicious.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet00Login;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet01LoginAcknowledge;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet02CharacterInfos;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet03CharacterInfosResponse;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet04RequestMatchmaking;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet05MatchmakingResponse;
import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet06StopMatchmaking;

public class PoulpiciousServer {

    private static class PoulpiciousServerHolder {
        private static final PoulpiciousServer _instance = new PoulpiciousServer();
    }

    public static PoulpiciousServer get() {
        return PoulpiciousServerHolder._instance;
    }

    private Server server;

    private Map<Integer, ServerPlayer> serverPlayers = new HashMap<Integer, ServerPlayer>();
    private List<Room> rooms;

    private Thread matchmakingEngineThread;

    public PoulpiciousServer() {
        this.server = new Server();
        this.rooms = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Room>());

        Kryo k = this.server.getKryo();
        k.register(Packet00Login.class);
        k.register(Packet01LoginAcknowledge.class);
        k.register(Packet02CharacterInfos.class);
        k.register(Packet03CharacterInfosResponse.class);
        k.register(Packet04RequestMatchmaking.class);
        k.register(Packet05MatchmakingResponse.class);
        k.register(Packet06StopMatchmaking.class);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            this.rooms.add(new Room());
            server.addListener(new PoulpiciousServerListener(this));

            this.matchmakingEngineThread = new Thread(MatchmakingEngine.get(), "matchmaking");
            this.matchmakingEngineThread.start();

            server.start();
            server.bind(25565, 25565);

            System.out.println("Master server started.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void registerPlayer(Connection c, String username) {
        this.serverPlayers.put(c.getID(), new ServerPlayer(c, username));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PoulpiciousServer().run();
    }

    public ServerPlayer getServerPlayer(int connID) {
        return this.serverPlayers.get(connID);
    }

    public Room getRoom(int index) {
        synchronized (rooms) {
            return this.rooms.get(0);
        }
    }

    public List<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

}
```

And the matchmaking engine:

```
package com.poulpicious.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.poulpicious.network.packets.Packet05MatchmakingResponse;

public class MatchmakingEngine implements Runnable {

    private static class MatchmakingEngineHolder {
        private static final MatchmakingEngine _instance = new MatchmakingEngine();
    }

    public static MatchmakingEngine get() {
        return MatchmakingEngineHolder._instance;
    }

    private boolean running;

    private ArrayList<ServerPlayer> playersSearching = new ArrayList<ServerPlayer>();

    public MatchmakingEngine() {
        this.running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (PoulpiciousServer.get().getRooms().size() > 0)
                System.out.println(PoulpiciousServer.get().getRooms().size());

            synchronized (playersSearching) {
                // System.out.println(playersSearching.size());
                if (playersSearching.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Matching a player");
                    ServerPlayer current = playersSearching.get(0);

                    PoulpiciousServer.get().getRoom(0).addPlayer(current);

                    Packet05MatchmakingResponse pmr = new Packet05MatchmakingResponse();
                    pmr.nbPlayers = PoulpiciousServer.get().getRoom(0).getPlayerCount();
                    current.getConnection().sendTCP(pmr);
                    playersSearching.remove(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void registerPlayer(ServerPlayer player) {
        synchronized (playersSearching) {
            this.playersSearching.add(player);
        }
    }

}
```

So in the main class I add a new Room, just for testing, so the rooms list contains at least 1 room.

In the matchmaking engine, in the run method, I want to print the size of this list but it doesn't, because the list is empty.

The problem is that I do not empty this list anywhere, and I don't understand why it is empty in the other thread.

I used synchronized, Collections.synchronizedList, even ConcurrentMap for testing, none worked...

How can I be sure that the list is really thread-safe and is not emptied for no reason ?

Comment: When you write `new PoulpiciousServer().run()` in your `main` method, why aren't you using `PoulpiciousServer.get().run()`? Surely then `PoulpiciousServer` isn't a singleton?

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PoulpiciousServer` isn't a singleton:

- You create one instance in the `PoulpiciousServerHolder` class
- You create one instance in the `PoulpiciousServer.main` method

You only call `PoulpiciousServer.run()` on the one created in the `main` method.

You access the list of rooms in the instance returned by `PoulpiciousServer.get()`, which is the instance created by the `PoulpiciousServerHolder` class. This one never has any rooms added to it, since its `run()` method is never invoked.

Replace the use of `new PoulpiciousServer()` in your `main` method with `PoulpiciousServer.get()`.

Comment: I changed it and it worked. I really didn't see this ! Thank you very much.